# Clipping a buffer from network analyst shapefile to a base shapefile

Tags: attribute-table, buffer, network, analysis, clip

I have exported my polygon shapefile which I got after I ran my Network Analyst into a shapefile. It has 6 buffer zones (delimited by time in increments of 10 minutes). When I check the attribute table it has my FromBreak, ToBreak and all the increments, etc.

Now I want to clip this buffer shapefile I have exported to my base shapefile (which is basically a municipality shapefile). Everything that is not included in this municipality shapefile, it's water.

Obviously I do not want my time buffer to run over water, however, when I clip the buffer to my municipality shapefile, the result shapefile loses it's buffer increments. Actually if I check the attribute table, it has the same attribute table my base shapefile had (the municipaility shapefile). How do I make the resulting shapefile after clipping to keep my buffer shapefile attributes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the layers may be out of order when you're running the [Clip tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000). Make sure the buffers layer is the input, and the municipal boundary is the clip feature.

I assume the buffers are in a polygon layer. Therefore, the municipal boundaries must also be a polygon.

Comment: Beautiful, it actually worked. No idea what was wrong the first time. I guess I did switched around the inputs. Tho I don't think the clip should've looked the same since the municipality shapefile is obviously much bigger. Anyway, it works now, thanks!